# R: merge elements of a list according to a vector of factors

Tags: r, list, merge

So, I have a list, that each elements is a vector. I have another vector of factors which I want to use to merge some of my list elements. As an example, here is some data:

```
> l <- list("0"=c("a", "b", "c", "a", "a"), "1"=c("c", "b", "c", "a", "c", "c", "c"), "2"=c("b", "b", "b"), "3"=c("d", "d", "a", "b", "d"))
> l
$`0`
[1] "a" "b" "c" "a" "a"

$`1`
[1] "c" "b" "c" "a" "c" "c" "c"

$`2`
[1] "b" "b" "b"

$`3`
[1] "d" "d" "a" "b" "d"

> f <- factor(c(1,2,2,1))
> f
[1] 1 2 2 1
Levels: 1 2
```

so according to this factor, I want to merge elements (1,4) and (2,3) since they have the same factor labels. My final list should look like this:

list.final:

```
$`0`
[1] "a" "b" "c" "a" "a" "d" "d" "a" "b" "d"

$`1`
[1] "c" "b" "c" "a" "c" "c" "c" "b" "b" "b"
```

So, only two elements, thereby merging elements 1,4  and 2,3 from the original list. Is there any way to do this using some apply functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the list on the factors and then recursively call `c`:

```
> lapply(split(l, f), function(x) unname(c(x, recursive = TRUE)))
$`1`
 [1] "a" "b" "c" "a" "a" "d" "d" "a" "b" "d"

$`2`
 [1] "c" "b" "c" "a" "c" "c" "c" "b" "b" "b"
```

in a similar manner you can use `unlist`

```
> lapply(split(l, f), function(x) unname(unlist(x)))
$`1`
 [1] "a" "b" "c" "a" "a" "d" "d" "a" "b" "d"

$`2`
 [1] "c" "b" "c" "a" "c" "c" "c" "b" "b" "b"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
  tapply(l, f, FUN=unlist,use.names=F)
  #$`1`
  #[1] "a" "b" "c" "a" "a" "d" "d" "a" "b" "d"

  #$`2`
  #[1] "c" "b" "c" "a" "c" "c" "c" "b" "b" "b"
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you only have two levels, you could use the list index.

```
> L <- unname(l)
> list(`0` = unlist(L[f == 1]), `1` = unlist(L[f != 1]))
$`0`
 [1] "a" "b" "c" "a" "a" "d" "d" "a" "b" "d"

$`1`
 [1] "c" "b" "c" "a" "c" "c" "c" "b" "b" "b"
```